# Why tailwind utilities and components does not work for me?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I've installed tailwind using `npm install tailwindcss` and I wrote

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

in input.css file, but it does not recognize `@tailwind` command and it gives error. When I run build command output.css file has only 500 lines of css code.
I use VSCode, and tailwind v3.
I configured everything according to the official tailwind docs.

Comment: Have you configured `content` in `tailwind.config.js`? The default output of Tailwind is about 543 lines if you don't have not configured the template paths, or don't have any Tailwind styles in those templates.

Comment: Which path should be configured in `content` ?

Comment: It is the path to where your website files are. It depends on what type of project you have as to where they will be. I would suggest read the documentation here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration

Answer (score 0):

Go to Visual Studio and to Extensions.
Search for PostCSS Language Support and install it.
After you have installed, the problem ist solved :D